# Creating a reusable RequireJs library

Tags: javascript, requirejs, bower, amd

Given the following simplified scenario, how could I best construct my reusable component so that it is correctly consumable by another application, such that foo.js prints 23?

---

**Reusable Component:**

```
/home.js
/main.js
/stuff
  foo.js
```

--

```
/home.js:
define([], function () { return 23; }

/stuff/foo.js:
define(['home'], function (home) { console.log(home); } // prints 23
```

---

**Consumer Application:**

```
/app.js
/main.js
/home.js
/views
  template.html
/bower_components
  /myReusableComponent
    /home.js
    /main.js 
    /stuff
      foo.js
```

--

```
/home.js:
define([], function () { return 17; }

/bower_components/myReusableComponent/home.js:
define([], function () { return 23; }

/bower_components/myReusableComponent/stuff/foo.js:
define(['home'], function (home) { console.log(home); } // now prints 17
```

---

Is there a consumer application requirejs config that sets the baseUrl of any module in /myReusableComponent to '/myReusableComponent'? My reusable component should not have/need access to the root level of the consumer application anyway.

I have looked into the r.js optimizer, but it just outputs a bunch of `define('stuff/foo', [], function ())`... what happens if the consumer application has a stuff/foo.js too?

The only solution I have found so far is forcing the use of relative paths in all of my modules: `define(['../home'], function (home) { console.log(home); }` but I am hoping there is a more elegant way to solve this problem.

All feedback is very appreciated!

Comment: I actually think in this case the relative path is the best option. You might be able to do something with packages: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages but I think that would put the burden of proper configuration on the consumer, which would likely be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce a library that is going to be usable in different applications, then you should use use relative paths when one module of your library refers to another, because this makes it more likely that whoever uses your library will be able to do so without having to do modify their RequireJS configuration.

Some clashes can be eliminated by the judicious use of `map` or `paths`. Ultimately, however, there are cases that cannot be solved (or at least not be solved as the user wants it) without having access to the unoptimized modules so you should distribute your library as an optimized bundle *and* provide the possibility to load it as a collection of unoptimized modules.