# Name collisions building a JavaScript library with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

We've decided to start using RequireJS for a JavaScript library we are developing. I'm rather new to RequireJS, and I wonder what I have to do in order to ensure that our library's module names don't collide with any module of applications that use our library. If for example I define module encoding.js:

```
define("encoding", ["dependency"], function(myDep) {
    ...
})
```

it seems that an application that uses my library, and has an encoding.js on its own, will result in a name collision. Is there any ReuireJS option I can use to "shield" my library's name from any application that uses our library?

Also, I know that the first parameter "encoding" is optional. The reason that I added it, is that we have used the minify-maven-plugin to build our library. This makes all the modules in the library end up in one file, and then it seems that I need to add the module name, or else I get the mismatched anonymous define module error (http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch). I guess I might use the r.js optimizing tool instead. Could that also be set up to remove the name collision issue?

In reality I guess we'll probably make our library RequireJS-agnostic by encapsulating the define call inside something like:

```
(function(root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define("encoding", ["dependency"], factory);
    } else {
        root.MyLib.Encoding = factory(MyLib.Deps);
    }
}(this, function() {
    ...
}))
```

I found this topic: [Creating a reusable RequireJs library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425273/creating-a-reusable-requirejs-library), but it didn't get a definite answer, and not exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When using RequireJS it is common practice (recommended practice actually) to not name the module. Naming them makes the modules less portable and will adversely affect the optimization tool.

RequireJS will take care of creating module names based on the file. Works well in my experience.

So your encoding module (encoding.js) would look like this

```
define(["dependency"], function(myDep) {
  ...
})
```

Assuming there isn't any special directory structure here, the encoding module could be use in `encoding_app.js` like so

```
requirejs(["encoding", "othermodule"],
  function (encoder, other) {
  }
);
```